# How to protect azure web app from abusive calls?

Tags: c#, azure, security, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have two web apps in azure one angular 6 the other one is .net core web api. Angular app consumes the apis to get data.  Some of these apis are public apis. It means authentication is not needed for them to be called.

My questions is, what the best approaches are to protect these public apis? By protecting, I mean not letting anonymous users to call these apis and abuse data.

In my mind these are what I can do:

1. CORS, but the problem is postman and other rest tool still can call my apis
2. Using azure api management? By rate limiting? Is there a better way?
3. Use some sort of api key but the angular app will expose them anyway.
4. In my c# app I get user agent, host, Origin of the call and restrict based on those?

Basically I want to restrict anonymous user from manipulating and calling my post apis and push not relevant or duplicate data to my back-end without using any sort of AD as my apis are going to be public. I want only a few authorized app can call my apis.

Please tell me which one of the above are the right one and please recommend a better approach.

P.S: my backend is .net core 2.2,

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you need to authenticate *users* to your APIs, not *apps*. Maybe start here? https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2017/09/06/secure-web-api-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: thanks for your reply @nlawalker. as I mentioned in the question, these apis are public api. they should not be behind any authentication.

Comment: You said "by protecting, I mean not letting anonymous users to call these apis and abuse data." Do you intend to allow anonymous users or not?

Comment: I want them stay public but I want only one caller can call them and the caller would be my angular app. now one else can get my apis from network tab in developer console and call my apis, especially the post ones

Comment: That's not possible. The code is running on the client's machine, you cannot prevent the user from inspecting network requests it makes, examining the code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend below solution,

1. Host your APIs on Azure API app and import it to APIM. Then Configure IP restriction on API APP using the IPs of APIM. That mean, only APIM can access your API host. or you can implement client certification authentication between APIM and API host.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates

02.Next enable subscription key/API key on APIM and keep these key on Azure key vault. So you don't need to hard code these keys on frontend. I hope you host this Angular app on Azure. (I am not Angular expert...just check online for docs)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-node

03.Later based on your scenario, If need you can apply Rate policies.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling.md

Comment: that's perfect, thank you. I understand step 1 and 3. I have a question about step 2, in the second step when the angular app/Node app tries to call the apim, in the network tab in the developer console in the browser aren't we exposing the subscription/API key? basically what I am asking is how does the node app will pass the api key to apim?

Comment: or on step 2) this will happen automatically whenever my angular app hosted in azure web app calls my apim, it will pass the key from key-vault by default? or is it something will happen manually through angular app when it calls the apim? Thanks

Comment: HI. you will keep the sub/API key on Azure Key vault. Then using some npm library, u can access that key on Angular app when u call APIs via APIM (So you can regenerate this key once a month or some time period). you have to code this part. Basically you will pass this key on HTTP header.  Then I hope, it will not visible on Network tab...IF not kindly check, what is the best practice to protect sensible data on Angular.                                                                          For you info, how it works on ASP net program,